# Pandas groupby: change values in one column based on values in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'll try to explain my problem as best as possible. But I'm new to Pandas, so please bear with me. I have a Pandas dataframe `df`:

```
    Random_ID   Seq_ID  Type    Seq Token
0   8             1     User    First
1   8             2     Agent   Second
2   8             3     User    Second
3   8             4     User    Second
4   8             5     Agent   Second
5   13            1     User    First
6   13            2     Agent   Second
7   13            3     User    Second
8   13            4     Agent   Second
9   13            5     User    Second
10  13            6     Agent   Second
11  13            7     User    Second
12  13            8     Agent   Second
13  13            9     User    Second
14  13            10    Agent   Second
```

I have been trying to change the values of `Seq Token`(User_First, Agent_Last...) based on the occurrence of `User` and `Agent` in `Type` in each group of `df.groupby('Random_ID')`. To illustrate further, take the last row of each group:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Random ID').last()
```

which gives:

```
          Seq_ID       Type     Seq Token
Random_ID           
8          5           Agent    Second
13         10          Agent    Second
```

Here, if `Type=Agent`, then `Seq token` should be `Agent_Final`. Then, the `df` should look like:

```
    Random_ID   Seq_ID  Type    Seq Token
0   8             1     User    First
1   8             2     Agent   Second
2   8             3     User    Second
3   8             4     User    Second
4   8             5     Agent   Agent_Final
5   13            1     User    First
6   13            2     Agent   Second
7   13            3     User    Second
8   13            4     Agent   Second
9   13            5     User    Second
10  13            6     Agent   Second
11  13            7     User    Second
12  13            8     Agent   Second
13  13            9     User    Second
14  13            10    Agent   Agent_Final
```

I've tried the following:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Random_ID', as_index=False).last()['Type']
for i in grouped:
    if i == 'Agent':
        df['Seq Token'] =  'Agent_Final'
```

but this assigns all items in `Seq token` as `'Agent_Final'`:

```
     Random_ID  Seq_ID  Type    Seq Token
0       8         1     User    Agent_Final
1       8         2     Agent   Agent_Final
2       8         3     User    Agent_Final
3       8         4     User    Agent_Final
4       8         5     Agent   Agent_Final
```

I read about `groupby` and it creates a copy of the original `df` and does not allow changing it unless one explicitly changes a `df[column]`. I hope this makes sense.

I've managed to set the first row "group values" to `"First"` using `np.where()` like this:

```
df['Seq Token'] = np.where((np.logical_and(np.equal(df['Type'],'User'), np.equal(df['Seq_ID'],1))), 'First', 'Second')
```

You can see that I've implemented this in the `df` already. Note that I used the `Seq_ID` value to get the first row in the group.

If there is a way to chain `np.where()` in such as way that I can assign `Seq Token` as `User_First`(same as First), `User_Middle`(if `Type=User` occurs in the middle), `Agent_Middle`(if `Type=Agent` occurs in the middle), `Agent_Last`(as explained above: if Agent is last), then it would be the most ideal solution. However, any other solutions are welcome too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you can using `index` assign after `groupby`

```
s=df.groupby('Random_ID').tail(1).loc[lambda x : x.Type=='Agent'].index
s
Out[62]: Int64Index([4, 14], dtype='int64')
df.loc[s,'SeqToken']='Agent_Final'
df
Out[64]: 
    Random_ID  Seq_ID   Type     SeqToken
0           8       1   User        First
1           8       2  Agent       Second
2           8       3   User       Second
3           8       4   User       Second
4           8       5  Agent  Agent_Final
5          13       1   User        First
6          13       2  Agent       Second
7          13       3   User       Second
8          13       4  Agent       Second
9          13       5   User       Second
10         13       6  Agent       Second
11         13       7   User       Second
12         13       8  Agent       Second
13         13       9   User       Second
14         13      10  Agent  Agent_Final
```

Comment: +1, Interesting, I was looking for a way to find the index for the grouped items and that's how you do it. I get the desired result for the last values. Now, if I want to do this for the middle and last values as well? Is there a compact way to achieve this? Maybe chain `np.where()` or `df.where()` or use list comprehensions. It should be simple yet Pythonic.

Comment: @user8212173  you mean you want the mid and last ? is the number of items in group always odd? If it have even number , you will check the forward or backward

Comment: Yes, the mid & last as well. The number of items is variable and has no particular pattern(even, odd). Another problem is that we must check if `Type=Agent` or `Type=User` which hasn't been done, so this partially resolves the problem.

Comment: I've modified the question and now I want to replace all the items in `SeqToken` column based on position of `User` or `Agent` in the `Type` column. The added condition in your answer has certainly helped and I'm constructing conditions based on it. I'll keep the question open in search of a compact solution that also performs well for large data-sets.

Comment: I managed to tokenize the first and last rows in `SeqToken` but not the mid rows with conditions.